# Windows Update failing with error code 0x80244018 when attempting to update to version 2004

Tags: windows-10, proxy, windows-update

When attempting to update to Windows 10 version 2004 from 1909, the error code 0x80244018 is encountered, which, as per [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolution-procedures#other-result-codes) link, pertains to the error caused by using a proxy server. This error code can be deemed irrelevant in this case as the machine encountering this error is not in any way connected to a proxy server, leaving next to no lead(s) regarding the underlying issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you attempting to install it through Windows Update or some other method?  [SetupDiag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag#setupdiag-in-windows-10-version-2004-and-later) is a critical tool to diagnose problems like this.  Please provide a screenshot of *Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings*

Comment: A Proxy server can also run on the PC itself, e.g. HTTP inspection proxies such as Fiddler.